# Query returns record in Rails console but Model resulting in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Context** - I am creating a quiz app to learn rails. A particular view displays list of questions and radio buttons. User has to select option for each question and click submit button. Submit button invokes an AJAX call and calls controller.

**Issue** - In Controller, the query returns

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

However when I run the same query in Rails console, I get a proper result.

Log Output -

> Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 29]]
>
> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Rails Console Output -

> Question Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 29]]
>   => #
>   irb(main):017:0>

**Model**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :title
end
```

**Table Schema**

```
create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "question"
  t.string   "option1"
  t.string   "option2"
  t.string   "option3"
  t.string   "option4"
  t.string   "answer"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "title_id"
end
```

**Controller**

```
  def check_answers
    answers = params[:answers]
    @response = []
    my_hash = {}
    answers.each_key do |key|
      question_id = answers[key]['question_id']
      user_answer = answers[key]['user_answer']
      correct_answer = Question.find_by id: question_id
      correct_answer_jk = correct_answer[0]['answer']
      my_hash['question_id'] = question_id
      my_hash['user_answer'] = user_answer
      if user_answer == correct_answer_jk
        my_hash['response'] = 'Correct'
        my_hash['correct_answer'] = ''
      else
        my_hash['response'] = 'Incorrect'
        my_hash['correct_asnwer'] = correct_answer_jk
      end
      @response.push(my_hash)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

I have googled the issue, but I am not getting any pointers to solve the issue. Please note I am using Sqlite.

**EDITED** development.log

> Started GET
>   "/questions_controller/check_answers?answers%5B0%5D%5Bquestion_id%5D=29&answers%5B0%5D%5Buser_answer%5D=B&answers%5B1%5D%5Bquestion_id%5D=30&answers%5B1%5D%5Buser_answer%5D=A&answers%5B2%5D%5Bquestion_id%5D=31&answers%5B2%5D%5Buser_answer%5D=D&answers%5B3%5D%5Bquestion_id%5D=32&answers%5B3%5D%5Buser_answer%5D=C&answers%5B4%5D%5Bquestion_id%5D=33&answers%5B4%5D%5Buser_answer%5D=B&answers%5B5%5D%5Bquestion_id%5D=34&answers%5B5%5D%5Buser_answer%5D=A&answers%5B6%5D%5Bquestion_id%5D=35&answers%5B6%5D%5Buser_answer%5D=B"
>   for ::1 at 2016-09-18 01:03:15 +0530 Processing by
>   QuestionsController#check_answers as */*   Parameters:
>   {"answers"=>{"0"=>{"question_id"=>"29", "user_answer"=>"B"},
>   "1"=>{"question_id"=>"30", "user_answer"=>"A"},
>   "2"=>{"question_id"=>"31", "user_answer"=>"D"},
>   "3"=>{"question_id"=>"32", "user_answer"=>"C"},
>   "4"=>{"question_id"=>"33", "user_answer"=>"B"},
>   "5"=>{"question_id"=>"34", "user_answer"=>"A"},
>   "6"=>{"question_id"=>"35", "user_answer"=>"B"}}} the incoming data is
>   {"0"=>{"question_id"=>"29", "user_answer"=>"B"},
>   "1"=>{"question_id"=>"30", "user_answer"=>"A"},
>   "2"=>{"question_id"=>"31", "user_answer"=>"D"},
>   "3"=>{"question_id"=>"32", "user_answer"=>"C"},
>   "4"=>{"question_id"=>"33", "user_answer"=>"B"},
>   "5"=>{"question_id"=>"34", "user_answer"=>"A"},
>   "6"=>{"question_id"=>"35", "user_answer"=>"B"}} the key is 0
>   [1m[36mQuestion Load (35.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "questions".* FROM
>   "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 29]]
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 35.2ms)
>
> NameError (undefined local variable or method `correct_answer_rels'
>   for #<QuestionsController:0x007ff3d50dd3a8>):
>
>   app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:27:in`block in check_answers'
>   app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:21:in `each_key'
>
>   app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:21:in`check_answers'
>
> Rendered
>   /Users/tusharsaurabh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
>   (3.7ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/tusharsaurabh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.8ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/tusharsaurabh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
>   (2.1ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/tusharsaurabh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
>   (89.5ms)

**Template**

check_answers.js.erb

```
<% @response.each do |my_hash| %>
<% if my_hash['response'] == 'Correct' %>
    $('#<%=my_hash["question_id"]%>').css('background-color','green');
<%else%>
    $('#<%=my_hash["question_id"]%>').css('background-color','red');
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Let's see your error trace or full development log. The could help in answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

For every request that you make which may be js/html, rails do check for view templates as action_name.html.erb/action_name.js.erb at app/views/controller_name directory depending on your request type.

So here do check by adding "check_answers.js.erb" file at respective directory. And specify your javascript there.

Or if you dont want to specify view templates, you should specify what to render at respond_to block as 
     format.js {render json: {your_json}}

Below part is not related to your question, but providing optimized and refactored code snippet of your code with some small corrections:

changes:
  1) Used each_value instead of each_key for hash, as you are dealing with values only.
  2) DB query moved to model.
  3) Changed the way my_hash is getting created.
  4) Reduced if-else loop to if

```
@response =[]
answers.each_value do |value|
    correct_answer = Question.get_saved_answer(value['question_id'])
    my_hash = {'question_id':  value['question_id'], 'user_answer': value['user_answer'], 'response': 'Correct'}
    if user_answer != correct_answer
        my_hash['response'] = 'Incorrect'
        my_hash['correct_asnwer'] = correct_answer
    end
    @response.push(my_hash)
end


Question.rb

def get_saved_answer(question_id)
    result = Question.find_by id: question_id
    result[0]['answer']
end
```

Hope it help you in some way as you continue to learn rails.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tushar. I already have a js.erb file corresponding to controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is trying to render a template on your Ajax request. If you don't specify what to render it will think you have a template to render. And if you don't you will get the 500 error

```
format.js {render json: {foo: 'bar'}}
```

Comment: Yes this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is expecting a view template for your `check_answers` action. As it does not find one in `app/views/your_controller`, it is responding with 500 status code. You should be able to see the error trace in your server logs.

To overcome this problem, please add a JS view template, for e.g. `check_answers.js.erb` in `app/views/your_controller` directory with appropriate JavaScript response.

Comment: I have the template present in View folder. I have provided the snapshot of template too.I am calling the template once, I have populated the variable response.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was  - I was expecting an array hence I coded -

```
correct_answer = Question.find_by id: question_id
correct_answer_jk = correct_answer[0]['answer']
```

However find_by won't return array, instead it will return a single Active Record:: Relation. Just removed the [0] and it worked.

Thanks everyone for your time and support.